# mutate function not adding column in r , it works with code run but original data frame in env don't have it

Tags: r

I am trying to compute some value using group by and trying to add the result back to data frame  in new variables using mutate function. But somehow its not working.

I have found many post with same problem on the forum and tried few I found relative like using <- assigning operator, chanting piping operator %<>% etc but neither has worked so far.

Here is my code. Please see what's wrong I am doing.

```
  library(dplyr)
  library(lubridate)
  df3 %>%
  group_by(Day = day(ymd_hms(timestamp))) %>%
  mutate(pressure_m = mean(pressure)) %>%
  mutate(pressure_s = sum(pressure))
```

I want pressure_m & pressure_s to be in the original data frame. These only shows when I run the above code. But in the data frame in environment, they are not.

Comment: Could you please share a sample of your data by using the function `dput(df3)`?

Comment: Have you tried overwriting the original dataset with `df3 <- df3 %>% ...`?

Comment: yes, as  I mentioned in OP using assignment through <-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df3 %>%
  group_by(Day = day(ymd_hms(timestamp))) %>%
  mutate(
    pressure_m = mean(pressure),
    pressure_s = sum(pressure)
  ) -> df3
```